# Trying to create a shared link in box.net using PHP

Tags: php, curl, put, box-api

Here is my code:

```
$params = array();
$params['shared_link'] = array("access"=> "Open");
$params = json_encode($params);
echo $params;
$key = "[key]";
$token = "[token]";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/[folder_id]/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
   "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=$key&auth_token=$token",'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params), 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

I am not being able to create a shared link. I get this response from box.net:

```
{"type":"error","status":500,"code":"internal_server_error","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Internal Server Error","request_id":"79086734650bfaf56c7894"}
```

Can somebody, please, help me on this?

Thanks!

Marcelo

Comment: Have you contacted Box.net support? Unfortunately a 500-series error would typically indicate there is something wrong on their side.  That is not to say that you haven't formed your request correctly (in which case they SHOULD give you a 400-series error), just that if you did form your request incorrectly, there are certainly not giving you any feedback to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, i could solve my problem.

The problem was that i wanted to create an "open" shared link with an enterprise token and apparently it is not possible (i am not 100% sure but, as per my attempts, i think so).

Thanks everyone for the help.

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL returned in their response, they give this information for 500 errors:

```
5xx
The request is fine, but something is wrong on Box’s end
```

So it sounds like you would need to contact Box about the issue.